# Access members in Map-like object in Groovy 3.x via dot notation throws Exception

Tags: groovy, vert.x

I'm using Vert.x 4.0.3 with Groovy 3.0.7 flavour -> `vertx-lang-groovy`. It has an extension module containing a method:

```
  public static Object getAt(JsonObject json, String key) {
    return json.getValue(key);
  }
```

Now, in my code I'm trying to get a member of `JsonObject`:

```
json.getString( 'id' ) // works fine
json[ 'id' ] // works fine
json.id // throws NoSuchMethodException
```

What am I missing?

Was the "dot notation" for `getAt()` somehow "deprecated" in Groovy 3?

UPDATE:

Indeed, the `getAt()` is not enough for the dot-notation, whereas the `getProperty()` is:

```
class A {
  String a = 'aaaaaaaaa'
  
  //Object getAt( String key ){ a }
   
  def getProperty(String name) { a }
}

def a = new A()

assert 'aaaaaaaaa' == a[ 'aa' ]
assert 'aaaaaaaaa' == a.aaaa
assert 'aaaaaaaaa' == a.a
```

Comment: It was not. But on the other end, there never was a need to override `getAt`?

Comment: `JsonObject` does NOT have `getAt`, so it was added by the extension

Comment: I deleted answer, had misread question.  Apologies.

Comment: Oh right, I assumed they are "map-ish" anyway. Well I think Jeffs answer shows the problem (and IMHO should not been deleted). `getAt` is used only if the object is map-ish.  So the question is rather: why has it worked before at all?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown do something with your answer so I can accept it

Comment: "Was the "dot notation" for getAt() somehow "deprecated" in Groovy 3?" - Did the code you show there behave differently in earlier versions of Groovy?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown it behaves differently in older versions of vert.x... I opened a ticket about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.id` is only valid if there is a `getId()` method, an `id` field, or something in place to intercept property access to instances of this class (`propertyMissing(String)`, `getProperty(String)`, etc.).  The `getAt(JsonObject, String)` method would not by default be involved in evaluating `json.id`.